# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly, WCF and ESRI Objects

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, web-service, wcf

I am getting this error when using ESRI objects like Geometry,  Envelope etc in a WCF service. I have a class that some properties (string, int, double) but when I add ESRI type as part of this class, it throws this error. Without ESRI objects, it wroks fine. I have tried to change the settings for timeout but that didn’t make any difference. I am hoping to get some feedback from other folks who have implementes ESRI objects from WCF service.

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at TEST.Services.Test.BoundaryService.IBoundaryService.GetBoundarySetSpatial(String boundarySetName, String boundaryName)
       at TEST.Services.Test.BoundaryService.BoundaryServiceClient.GetBoundarySetSpatial(String boundarySetName, String boundaryName) in C:\Projects\TESTGeoServices\TEST.Services.Test\Service References\BoundaryService\Reference.cs:line 57
       at TEST.Services.Test.BoundaryServiceTest.BoundaryService_GetBoundarySetSpatial_Test() in C:\Projects\TESTGeoServices\TEST.Services.Test\BoundaryServiceTest.cs:line 26
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you [running it on an STAThread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260243/125400)?

Comment: I am not quite sure of STAThread, can't confirm if I am using STAThread or not. In terms of setup, have a wcf service and then BL class for logic and have Bo that has some properties. For this Bo, trying to add some properties like Geometry, Envelope etc.

Comment: Is Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() == ApartmentState.STA ?

Comment: More info [here](http://scottseely.com/2009/07/17/calling-an-sta-com-object-from-a-wcf-operation/).

Comment: Could you provide more details? How does your WCF service contract look like? Are you referencing ESRI COM objects or interfaces in a WCF operation/data contract? If that's the case, you will need to define your own non-COM classes representing the data contract and convert between these and ESRI COM objects, so that at no point are ESRI COM objects exposed in the public contract.

Comment: That said, it is most likely a serialization issue. You could turn on WCF tracing to see what exactly fails.

Comment: Hi Petr, I have a map service as part of my solution and that gives me access to ESRI objects. In my class, I just referencing this service.

Comment: This is a good point on serialization, in my class, i am just addign this as a property: public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }

Comment: <Message>There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetBoundarySetSpatialListResult. The InnerException message was 'Type TEST.Services.Data.BoundaryMapService.PolygonN' with data contract name 'PolygonN:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TEST.Services.Data.BoundaryMapService' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'Message>

Comment: Sorry, but that is not sufficient info. Can you paste the complete contract interface and the types it references? From what you describe it's not actually clear whether PolygonN and Geometry are ESRI COM types, ESRI SOAP WebServices library types, or whether they are defined elsewhere (or by you).